# What is the extension of an app?

Tags: android, icons, bytecode, dalvik

I searched for what are the executable files in Android and I have found some extensions like .dex (dalvik bytecode). But whenever I tap on any .dex file it cannot actually run on Android platform explicitly (even the main activity class which is the entry point of Android app). I want to know what is the extension of Android apps? Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Clicking on a app icon sends a command to application manager to start the Launcher activity of the app.

Comment: Can we launch an Android app from tapping on file having that launcher activity? If yes then where to find that file?

Answer (score 1):

The extension of android application is .apk.
Android executable concept is not like windows executable(.exe).
Dalvik is a virtual machine where every android application runs.

All apk's basic source code is in java language . When you build this project all .java files get converted to .class now the dx tool of adk converts all .class files to classes.dex file .And this classes.dex file is executed on dalvik virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks Mad code. I want to know what is the file format of Android app ICON? Like, when I tap on WhatsApp icon it starts running the app. I mean this icon is kind of executable because it starts running the app. So what is it's extension? Or how this app icon triggers the app activity? What is he source code of this app icon which actually starts the activity

Comment: App icon is an icon that we given in manifest file,it is a png format file.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aa.bb.cc">
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    </application>
</manifest>

while we clicking an app icon android system starts running the application.

Comment: Every android application has a manifest file.Icon for the application must be defined in manifest file.

Comment: Now about icon shown in application list.Every android system has a launcher application it is responsible for showing application list.This launcher application using the icons defined in each application manifest to create application list.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation points and cannot publicly vote

Answer (score 0):

Android app extension is **.apk** stands for **Application Package Kit**